# ID and Email are returned as null

Tags: firebase, flutter, email, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I store an id(nanoid) and email as fields of userinfo document. But when I retrieve userinfo all other fields like name, phone,are returned but id and email returned null. When I look through the console id and email fields have data (they are not null) but when I retrieve them through streambuilder they are returned null.
Also in all other documents that have id and email fields they are returned null while they have data when I look through the console.
help please.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: As @Josteve mentioned, please provide the code so we can help you better.